# Arithmetic operations on map index, cpp

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

1. I have written a function which scans through a directory and stores them in a map of form  `map<int, string>mymap`
2. All the file names in the directory are positive integers hence the key for map is the file name in `int` and the value is the actual filename which is a `string`
3. I am trying to do the following operation (Print consecutive  differences between the values present from the end of the map)

   ```
   map<int, string>::reverse_iterator rit = file_map.rbegin();

   int size = file_map.size();

   // trying to find the consecutive difference between indices
   for ( int i = size; i>1 ; i--) {
       cout << " diff is " <<(int) (rit->first) - (int)((++rit)->first) << endl;
   }
   ```

With this I am not able to print the differences or the ordering will be wrong if I do a `rit++` instead  of a `++rit`.

is there a right way to do it?

Comment: So I am storing each of the index in a temp value and then finding the difference.

Comment: The order of evaluation of the subtraction's operands is unspecified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are not using C++11, so let's add our own version of [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
template<class ForwardIt>
ForwardIt next(ForwardIt it,
    typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::difference_type n = 1)
{
    std::advance(it, n);
    return it;
}
```

With that, we can just iterate forwards:

```
if (file_map.size() >= 2) {
    map<int, string>::iterator it = file_map.begin();
    map<int, string>::iterator end = next(file_map.end(), -1);

    for (; it != end; ++it) {
        cout << " diff is " << next(it)->first - it->first << endl;
    }
}
```

You don't need to cast `first` to an `int`, it already is one.

Comment: Can I do this with a reverse iteration/iterator?

Comment: Yeah, same way - just changes the types and `begin()/end()` to `rbegin()/rend()`.